# algorithm for sum up a list and each of their product?

Tags: algorithm

```
function sum(arr){
let count = 0;
let count1 = 0;
for(let i = 0; i<arr.length;++i){
     count = arr[i] + count}
for(let j = 0; j < arr.length;++j){
    if(j === arr.length - 1){
       break}
    count1 = arr[j] * arr[j + 1] + count1;}
count = count + count1;
return count;
}
```

I implemented above's code to calculating the sum of numbers and each of their product in an array. For example, if array = [1,2,3], then it would be 1+2+3+1*2+2*3 = 14. However, writing two separate for loop seems silly to me, is there a more elegant way to do this? In addition, I'm stuck on prove this algorithm's correctness and the running time. But it looks like O(n) + O(n)= 2O(n) = O(n) to me. For proving the correctness, I think induction is a way to do it but currently I'm having trouble of using induction to prove an algorithm.

Comment: You can do this in JavaScript with a one liner : `arr.reduce((acc,b,idx) => acc + b + b * (idx !== 0 ? arr[idx - 1] : 0), 0)`. As for run-time and correctness, all proofs will be  similar to the case of a program with one loop.

Answer (score 0):

Simple modification:

```
function sum(arr){
let count = arr[0];
for(let i = 1; i<arr.length;++i){
     count = count + arr[i] * (arr[i-1] + 1);    }
return count;
}
```

And yes, you are right about `O(n) + O(n)= 2O(n) = O(n)` because constants are ignored